# How to build relationship in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I have 2 nodes: People and Friends with next structures: 
people: p_id;           Friends:           p_id, f_id

I need to build relation [:KNOWS] between them.

How can i do that? I'm new in Neo4J.

P.S. I'm using Cypher

Comment: I think you're confused about what a node is. A node is the graph equivalent of a *row* in the relational world, not the equivalent of of a table. I mean, People and Friends are really strange names for nodes/labels, and `f_id` looks like some kind of foreign key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do it for you.  Basically, you need to explicitly match both of the nodes with which you want to create a relationship and then create the relationship with the direction you want between the the two referenced nodes.

```
MATCH (p:People), (f:Friend)
WHERE p.id = 'xx' 
AND f.id = 'xy'
CREATE (p)-[:KNOWS]->(f)
```

The ref card - http://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/ - has been invaluable to me in working through the intricacies of cypher.

Comment: But how can i do this for all id's in both nodes?

Comment: you need to build the relationships using the p_id to f_id relationship. If you have all of the relationships in a csv then you can use the "load csv" process. to load them. something like this should work... LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Y:/pid_to_f_id.csv" AS rel
MATCH (p:Person { id: rel.p_id}),(f:Friend { id: rel.f_id })
create (p)-[:KNOWS]->(f)

Comment: This query reurned to me 0 rows.

Comment: sorry - the query is not intended to return rows, it is intended to read data from a csv file and bulk create your relationships based on user entries you have already created.  Do you have some sample data?